# c++ can't init a value capture lambda by std::function if it's a recursive func

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I'm trying t write a recursive lambda warped by `std::function` like this:

```
function<int(int)> fib {[&](int n) {
  assert( n >= 0 );
  if( n < 2 ) return val;
  else
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}};
```

It's worked, but if I change the capture method from '`&`' to '`=`', I found this code can be compiled but will core(segmentation fault) at fib init.

That's why?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is mostly similar to valid `void* p = &p;` against UB `int i = i;`

Comment: With = you copy an unitialized fib.

Comment: To add to @mfnx 's point, the reason this is happening is because the assignment to `fib` is the *last* thing to happen, meaning that when `fib` is copied during the lambda's creation it is undefined. However, if you use a reference, it simply copies the location of `fib` in memory, and not the value itself. Therefore the reference becomes valid after the  lambda is assigned to `fib` at the end of the statement.

Comment: anyone know why this recursive lambda definition is legal as a "one liner"? I thought to make a recursive lambda you had to declare a variable of type std::fuction first and then assign that variable to a lambda that captures the std::function or else you would be capturing an incomplete type.